# Make $var set in a PHP file work in other PHP file included/required by the initial one

Tags: php, include, require

I have a following code in the initial PHP file:

```
$var = $another_var;
echo 'Some text '.$var.' some more text.';
```

The code which produces `$another_var` can not be moved to any other file.

Now I want every text string of the whole initial PHP file including the one in the example to put to an extra PHP file and `include` or `require` it by the initial one. Like this:

```
// required.php file
$text_string_1 = 'Some text '.$var.' some more text.';
```

and

```
// Initial PHP file
<?php require('required.php'); ?>
$var = $another_var;
<div><?php echo $text_string_1; ?>
```

Expectedly it doesn't work. I assume that's because the required.php file knows nothing about the `$var`'s value as it was set in another file which is just going to adopt required.php.

Is there any workaround for this? Preferably keeping both files as simple as possible.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear what you're trying to do or what your exact issue is. But essentially, it's pretty straight forward. If you want to use a variable that's defined in file A in file B, then you need to include/require file A in file B before you can use it. You can then include file B in file C and get access to the variable in file A. Not sure if that is what you're asking or not. If not, please clarify the question.

Comment: May be to treat the external and initial files just like a single file. Sorry, I can't explain better, English is not my mother's language.

Comment: If you want to write a variable using another variable, like `'foo' . $var . 'bar'`, you must define `$var` before that. In your example, you need to first do `$var = $another_var;` and then after that require `required.php`.

Comment: I haven't said "internal". Have I?

Comment: Sorry, I misread :-) You simply can't use or reference variables before they are defined. If you want to create strings and substitute parts later on, you need to implement some placeholders instead that you replace when you want to use them.

Comment: Ok. I'll try to explain the other way. May be it is possible to prevent any code execution in both files until the external one becomes the integral (not internal) part of the initial one. Like you press ctrl-a>ctrl-c and get the content of both files at the same time, in predefined parts order. May be it is possible to virtually construct the third PHP file which will contain parts of both files in correct order and execute this third file. Once again, I can't explain better in a foreign language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change to a template approach.  And substitute later:

```
<?php

$template = 'Hello %s, this could be a solution.';

$txt = sprintf($template, 'Foo');

echo $txt;
```

Output:

```
Hello Foo, this could be a solution.
```

Comment: It just works. And pretty elegant. I really appreciate your input, thank you very much!